# How to make dateutil.parse() still be agnostic to format, but require day, month and year from the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-dateutil

I use dateutil.parse() to parse out datetime strings from a file. Once in a while these strings are not actual date times. All kinds of things can be there.

My trouble is that parse() gives me false positives when I do not want it to parse. For example:
`dateutil.parse("99")` turns into a `datetime` with today's date and with the year 1999.

**How could I make it to raise an exception if parse() is not passed a string with year, day, and month (in various formats)?**

Comment: You mean `dateutil.parser.parse`. Indeed, even [1A2B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75072208/357313) is a valid date, but it gives a warning. :-/