# Why does read_csv give me a timezone warning?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, python-dateutil

I try reading a CSV file using pandas and get a warning I do not understand:

```
Lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py:1207: UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname B identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
  warnings.warn("tzname {tzname} identified but not understood.  "
```

I do nothing special, just `pd.read_csv` with `parse_dates=True`. I see no `B` that looks like a timezone anywhere in my data. What does the warning mean?

A minimal reproducible example is the following:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('x\n1A2B'), index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

Why does pandas think `1A2B` is a datetime?!

To solve this, I tried adding `dtype={'x': str}` to force the column into a string. But I keep getting the warning regardless...

Comment: Convenience is not always clever. You might want to consider not parsing dates during read_csv, or at least specify which columns to parse. Keyword `parse_dates` alternatively takes a list or dict to specify that ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `1A2B` is being interpreted as "1 AM on day 2 of the current month, timezone B". By default, [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) uses `dateutil` to detect datetime values (`date_parser=`):

```
import dateutil.parser
dateutil.parser.parse('1A2B')
```

Apart from the warning, this returns (today):

```
datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 2, 1, 0)
```

And B is not a valid timezone specifier indeed.

Why adding `dtype` doesn't help stays to be investigated.

I did find a simple [hack that works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8435089/357313):

```
import dateutil.parser
def dateparse(self, timestr, default=None, ignoretz=False, tzinfos=None, **kwargs):
    return self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
dateutil.parser.parser.parse = dateparse  # Monkey patch; hack!
```

This prevents using the current day/month/year as defaults, rendering the value invalid as a `datetime` as expected.